# JFrame window is not closing

Tags: java

so i was trying to make a quiz application but i got this error below

I Want to close the JFrame window so i tried setVisible(false); to close window if someone click back button but it is not working help me as im new. i even tried Jframe.dispose(); and other methods i dont what error i have made if you help me pls

```
  import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Login extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
   JButton Rules,Back;
   

   Login() {
       getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
       ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("icon/login.jpeg"));//<-- to pick images from directory
       setLayout(null);
       JLabel image = new JLabel(i1);

       JLabel heading = new JLabel("Quiz Bazzi");
       heading.setBounds(750,50,300,50);
       heading.setFont(new Font("Mongolian Baiti",Font.BOLD,42));
       heading.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
       add(heading);

       JLabel name = new JLabel("Enter Your Name");
       name.setBounds(785,150,350,20);
       name.setFont(new Font("Mongolian Baiti",Font.BOLD,18));
       name.setForeground(Color.black);

       add(name);

       JTextField tfname = new JTextField();
       tfname.setBounds(715,180,300,25);
       tfname.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,18));
       tfname.setForeground(Color.black);
       add(tfname);

       Rules = new JButton("Rules");
       Rules.setBounds(715,220,120,25);
       Rules.setBackground(Color.black);
       Rules.setForeground(Color.white);
       add(Rules);

       Back = new JButton("Back");
       Back.setBounds(895,220,120,25);
       Back.setBackground(Color.black);
       Back.setForeground(Color.white);
       add(Back);

       image.setBounds(0,0,500,400);
       add(image);

       setSize(1200,439);
       setLocation(180,100);
       setVisible(true);

   }  
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       if(e.getSource() == Rules){
           setVisible(true);
       } else if (e.getSource() == Back) {
           setVisible(false);

       }


   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Login();
   }
}
```

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information.  Are you sure you’re extending JFrame?  Are you sure you’re displaying that same JFrame instance?  If `Rules` is a component in that JFrame, how can it make its own JFrame ancestor visible?  What “back button” are you talking about?

Comment: hey i have edited this post so you can check again

Comment: `actionPerformed` is never called, because you never called `addActionListener` on either of your buttons.

Comment: oh thanks man don't know i forgot about it thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what it the purpose of:

```
JFrame.dispose();
```

?

It is exactly what you need :)

Comment: i tried dispose(); but still not working